# iOS split NSString into NSArray delimited by byte 1

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a string separated by byte "1". Now I want to split this string 
How to do this.

```
[str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]
```

works fine but only for string delimiter not for byte.

Pls help

Comment: could you please show an example of your str?

Comment: How does the NSString contain byte middle of it? Post your string to be delimited.

Comment: What do you mean by "byte 1"? Do you mean the character with ASCII value 1?

Comment: yes character with ASCII value 1

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about strings that are separated by the ASCII character with a hex value of 0x01, then you can do:

```
NSArray *substrings = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"\u0001"];
```

The sequence `\u0001` gets translated to the Unicode character with hex code 1.

Comment: sorry for responding so late. was bit busy with development
It is not splitting my string having this byte 1